# How can I get down time of a specific deployment in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring

I have an use case where I need to collect the **downtime of each deployment** (if all the replicas(pods) are down at the same point of time).

**My goal is to maintain the total down time for each deployment since it was created.**

I tried getting it from **deployment status**, but the problem is that I need to make frequent calls to get the deployment and check for any down time.

Also the **deployment status** stores only the latest change. So, I will end up missing out the changes that occurred in between each call if there is more than one change(i.e., **down time**). Also I will end up making multiple calls for multiple deployments frequently which will consume more compute resource.

Is there any reliable method to collect the **down time data of an deployment**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A monitoring tool like prometheus would be a better solution to handle this. 
As an example, below is a graph from one of our deployments for last 2 days

[image: Deployment Availablity]

If you look at the blue line for unavailable replicas, we had one replica unavailable from about 17:00 to 10:30 (ideally unavailable count should be zero)

This seems pretty close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will try this.